# SQLite3 (iOS) query not executing

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I'm having some trouble getting this to work.

This is the code I want to execute:

```
[self openDB];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSString *sql2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CheckList (CLName, DateAdd, Active, Costum, Percentage, UserId) VALUES ('ola232332332324', '2012-02-03', 1, 1, NULL, 1)"];
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql2 UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]
              initWithTitle:@"Grats" message:@"The query was executed!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert1 show];
    [alert1 release];
} 
else {
    NSAssert(0, @"Failed to execute");
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

And this is the code I use to call the db:

```
-(NSString *) filePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"prosegur.sqlite"];
}

-(void) openDB {
    sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db);
    if (sqlite3_open([[self filePath] UTF8String], &db) != SQLITE_OK){
        NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open db");
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Trying to use the FMDB, here's the code:

```
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"prosegur.sqlite"];
if([database open]){
    NSLog(@"yes");
    [database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO CheckList (CLName, DateAdd, Active, Costum, UserId) VALUES ('cenas', '2012-02-0',  1, 1, 1)"];}
else
{
    NSLog(@"not");
}
```

Passes by the [database open] verification, but it doesn't execute the query.

**EDIT 2:** Already did what it was suggested, i'm starting to think that it creates a database and executes the query inside of it, but since it doesn't exist any table, it ignores that fact.

Here's the updated code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] retain];
NSString *path = [[docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"prosegur.sqlite"] retain];

FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
[database open];
if([database open])
{
    NSLog(@"yes");
    [database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO CheckList (CLName) VALUES (?)", @"cenas"];
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"no");
}
[database close];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer, if anyone is having troubles like this, check out the following link:
[IPhone Development - Failed to use SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527094/iphone-development-failed-to-use-sqlite)

Thanks to all of you for the support!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a silly question, but you are aware that `sqlite3_prepare_v2` only *prepares* the statement and does not actually *execute* it? You also need to call `sqlite3_step` to actually do the insert,

You could use `sqlite3_exec` instead, which simply executes a statement without doing the prepare/execute two-step.

Comment: Well my problem is that he doesn't get the sqlite3_prepare_v2 (..) ==SQLITE_OK verification right, he always goes to else. i can't see anything right with that sentence. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have had a lot of headache while using standart sqlite3 api in iOS development.
Check out [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) framework. It is very simple to use, and you can find lots of tutorials on the web.

If you do not want that framework, try using `NSError` for catching an error on query execution.

Comment: I will try that, if i can't make this working im really thinking to go with a coredata app. thanks msj! :)

Comment: You can't use `NSError` as SQLite is a C-level API and `NSError` is Objective C.

Comment: Yes. My fault. About FMDB - it is a wrapper around SQLite. So it supports real SQL queries, and is really easier to use than Core Data.

Comment: Edited the topic, i'd kill for some help, this is an academic work :(

Comment: In your provided code you do not use actual path to your database. You should provide full path. This is how I get actual path for database:
`+(NSString *) databasePath;
{
    NSString *databaseName = @"socialpad.sqlite";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    return databasePath;
}`

Change the path to your database in `[FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"prosegur.sqlite"];`

Comment: @RodolfoMatos And also it is quite nice to use the next syntax: `[database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO CheckList (CLName, DateAdd, Active, Costum, UserId) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",@"cenas", @"2012-02-0",  1, 1, 1, nil];` (you get an idea). It is preferred as FMDB will do some of the sanitizing for your (such as add slashes to single quotes). Very useful tutorial on FMDB: http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/

Comment: thank you for your answers, tried that out and it didn't worked, i guess it was to do with the database path, he says that it can connect to the db but actually doesn't. is the database supposed to be where? resources? i actually don't know. I'm really thank you for you help msj and the others! :)

Comment: @RodolfoMatos the database should be in your iphone simulator folder. For me it is in a `/Users/msj/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/56C9CFB2-CB34-4A43-BE33-0F7EF98FFA0D/Documents/databasename.sqlite`. If it is not there, probably you haven't created it in your `appDidFinishLoading` method (or wherever you are creating it).

Comment: @RodolfoMatos, btw, this file could be opened with free Firefox addon "SQLite Manager". You can find it here: http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/

Comment: I'm using that addon, i think i'm doing everything right. dunno why this doesn't work :(

Comment: @RodolfoMatos i will look at your code, if you pack and drop your project somewhere. But now i have no mac near me, so it would be done in 6 hours, i think.

Comment: thank you soooo much for the help, already solved it. here the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527094/iphone-development-failed-to-use-sqlite happy codding msj :D

Answer (score 1):

Sample Example.

```
+(BOOL)InsertDataInPin:(NSString *)pin
    {
        NSString *databasePath =Your DatabasePath;

        NSString *SQL=@"INSERT INTO pincode Values(?)";
        sqlite3_stmt *dataset;


        if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK ) {

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [SQL UTF8String], -1, &dataset, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
            {

                sqlite3_bind_text(dataset, 1, [pin UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                sqlite3_step(dataset);

            }       

            sqlite3_close(database);
        }


    }
```